# Error Plecost - Wordpress finger printer Tool

Tags: python, wordpress, security, plugins, pip

I am trying to use "plecost".
I installed python3 and pip to use it.
Finding the following error:

```
manjaro@arch➜~» plecost                                                  [18:39:35]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/plecost", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plecost_lib/plecost.py", line 78, in main
    from .api import run, __version__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plecost_lib/api.py", line 46, in <module>
    from .libs.data import PlecostOptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plecost_lib/libs/data.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .utils import get_data_folder
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/plecost_lib/libs/utils.py", line 41, in <module>
    import aiohttp
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import hdrs  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/hdrs.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .multidict import upstr
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/multidict.py", line 285, in <module>
    class _ItemsView(_ViewBase, abc.ItemsView):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/abc.py", line 133, in __new__
    cls = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace)
TypeError: multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict
```

Any idea how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install latest version of aiohttp library

```
sudo python3 -m pip install aiohttp==1.3.5
```

If you get "ImportError: cannot import name HTMLParseError" you have to upgrade beautifulsoup4

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
```